# rspec helper user_signed_in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I have a helper method that returns one link `if user_signed_in?`. I'm using Devise 2.2.8, Rails 3.2.2 and Rspec 3.4.0.

**application_helper.rb**

```
def session_button
  if user_signed_in?
    link_to "Restricted Area", user_index_path
  else
    link_to "Login", new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

And my test:

**application_helper_spec.rb**

```
describe "#session_button" do
  context "user signed in" do
    login_user

    it "returns a link to Restricted Area" do
      expect(session_button).to include "Área Restrita"
      expect(session_button).to include user_index_path
    end
  end

  context "user not signed in" do
    it "returns a link to New Session" do
      expect(session_button).to include "Login"
      expect(session_button).to include new_user_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

`login_user` is a macro included in my tests. I also loaded `TestHelpers`.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :helper
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :helper
end
```

The problem: I'm getting this error:

```
1) ApplicationHelper#session_button user signed in returns a link to Restricted Area
   Failure/Error: if user_signed_in?

   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `user_signed_in?' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationHelper::SessionButton::UserSignedIn:0x0000000795a608>
```

I also tried to stub the method

```
allow(helper).to receive(:user_signed_in?).and_return(true)
```

but I get the same error.

How do I stub this devise helper?

Comment: Does this work when you run it in the browser? ie is this an error in your code or just in the test?

Comment: Yes, it works in the browser. The error is just in the test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way using anonymous helper but I don't know if there is a better way...

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, :type => :helper do
  helper do
    def user_signed_in?
      user.present?
    end
  end

  describe "#session_button" do
    context "user signed in" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }

      it "returns a link to Restricted Area" do
        expect(session_button).to include "Área Restrita"
        expect(session_button).to include user_index_path
      end
    end

    context "user not signed in" do
      let(:user) { nil }

      it "returns a link to New Session" do
        expect(session_button).to include "Login"
        expect(session_button).to include new_user_session_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```